# How do I specify a nodePort for Confluent Schema Registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

With reference to the following helm chart:
https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts

I am trying to make the schema registry available to pods within the k8s cluster. To do that I added a nodePort to the values.yaml and the service.yaml:

values.yaml:

```
## External access.
##
external:
  enabled: true
  # type can be either NodePort or LoadBalancer
  type: NodePort
  nodePort: 31095
```

service.yaml:

```
spec:
  ports:
    - name: schema-registry
      port: {{ .Values.servicePort }}
      nodePort: {{ .Values.external.node_port }}
```

When I deploy the chart, the nodePort doesn't appear:

```
kubectl get svc cp-schema-registry -n kafka-namespace
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
cp-schema-registry   ClusterIP   10.4.26.199   <none>        8081/TCP   34m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a typo in the service.yaml file. In the values file we have:

```
external:
  enabled: true
  # type can be either NodePort or LoadBalancer
  type: NodePort
  nodePort: 31095
```

service.yaml refers to value for node port: node_port which doesn't exist in the values.yaml. Changing this to:

```
nodePort: {{ .Values.external.nodePort }}
```

fixed the issue.